# LIstbox Selected Item content to textblock

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, listbox

I am sure there is a simple solution to this, but I can't seem to find it at the moment.

I am trying to disaply the content of the selection listbox in a textblock as text using the below code.

```
private void SelectionToText(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ListBoxItem selection = (ListBoxItem)TextListBox.SelectedItem;

    selectionText.Text = "This is the " + selection;

}
```

For some reason the textblock just displays

> "This is the System.Windows.Controls.ListBoxItem "

I initial thought it was because I hasn't converted to a string, but that didn't work either.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do not cast to ListBoxItem at first. What is the type of your content of ListBox?

Comment: @EugeneCheverda Content of listbox is string, eg.. "item1"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reference the Content property of the ListBoxItem

```
selectionText.Text= "This is the " + selection.Content.ToString();
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I can't believe I missed that. I think I need to get some sleep. That worked fine. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

```
string selText = selection.Items[selection.SelectedIndex].Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom class

```
public class MyListBoxItem
{
    public MyListBoxItem(string value, string text)
    {
        Value = value;
        Text = text;
    }

    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Text;
    }
}
```

Add items to your `ListBox` like:

```
listBox1.Items.Add(new MyListBoxItem("1", "Text"));
```

And this will work

```
private void SelectionToText(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyListBoxItem selection = (MyListBoxItem)TextListBox.SelectedItem;

    selectionText.Text = "This is the " + selection;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong, you need to do the following code

```
Convert.ToString(TextListBox.SelectedItem);
```

This will return the value of SelectedItem

Answer (score 0):

Please write as this:

```
private void SelectionToText(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyListBoxItem selection = (MyListBoxItem)TextListBox.SelectedItem;

    selectionText.Text = "This is the " + selection.Content.ToString();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do it without code behind, in silverlight, by binding the text property of the textblock to the selecteditem.content property of the listbox.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Content, ElementName=list}"/>
```

Where list is the name of my ListBox.