# How can I use the content of a listbox in an if-statement

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a listbox with content (the numbers 1-2-3-4-5-6)
How can I use a selected number in an if-statement?

Now I have something like that:

```
if (Listbox1.SelectedItem.ToString()=6)
{
...
}
```

The XAML for my listbox is:

```
<ListBox x:Name="lb_getallen" 
         HorizontalAlignment = "Center" 
         Height = "124" 
         Margin = "428,28,54,0" 
         VerticalAlignment = "Top" 
         Width = "35" 
         HorizontalContentAlignment = "Center"> 

         <ListBoxItem Content = "1"/> 
         <ListBoxItem Content="2"/> 
         <ListBoxItem Content="3"/> 
         <ListBoxItem Content="4"/> 
         <ListBoxItem Content="5"/> 
         <ListBoxItem Content="6"/> 
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Do you mean, instead of selected item, you want to use any other item?

Comment: Take a look at the examples of `.SelectedValue` in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4902039/difference-between-selecteditem-selectedvalue-and-selectedvaluepath) for a way to use the actual value of a listbox.

Comment: @FiliepVerpoucke how do you populate your `ListBox`? Update your question with relevant XAML/code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LIstbox Selected Item content to textblock](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7887829/listbox-selected-item-content-to-textblock)

Answer (score 1):

If you added the numbers as `int`s you can use this:

```
if (Listbox1.SelectedItem == 6)
{
    // do something
}
```

Otherwise this would work too:

```
if (Listbox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "6")
{
    // do something
}
```

Note that a comparison is done by `==`. A single `=` is used for assignment.

`ToString()` returns a `string`, so you cannot compare it to an `int` like `6`, but to `"6"`.